# How would I move the background image of an object without moving the other contents inside it?

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    background-image: url(http://web.archive.org/web/20110330221051if_/http://www.roblox.com/images/cssthemes/outrageous2/bkg.jpg);

    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0px 155px;
}

h1, p {
 color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>TEXT 1 - H1</h1>
<p>TEXT 2 - P</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what my setup looks like, simplified. What I want to do is make the background start at 0px 155px. What happens when I use background-position, is that the background loops around at the top. Instead of this I want the area above it to be white.

This is easy to do with a top: 155px or similar, but what I want to accomplish is the text staying in place.

I'm CSS modding a website so I can't add any new HTML. Is this possible?

Edit: I need it repeating in both the X and Y directions.

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: The image I chose was only an example, I want it repeating in the y direction too, but only downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to create the background layer and you can easily control the position:

```css
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:150px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(http://web.archive.org/web/20110330221051if_/http://www.roblox.com/images/cssthemes/outrageous2/bkg.jpg);
  margin:0;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEXT 1 - H1</h1>
<p>TEXT 2 - P</p>
```

Comment: This kind of works, but it doesn't really solve the problem. It only hides the area, it doesn't move it downwards. I'm not just using this tiled background, there are many others, some of which look really bad when part of them are obscured. I also want to be able to set the white color to transparent, but when I do the background beneath it is shown.

Comment: Yes! After some tweaking this works exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks!